# Как отредактировать сообщение в topic, aiogram?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Написал бота тех поддержки через topic.

1. Пользователь пишет боту
2. Бот создает topic в групе для общения с этим пользоватем (если нет)

Вопрос. Если пользователь написал сообщение "Hello World", бот отправил сообщение в topic. И потом пользователь решил отредактировать сообщения, как поменять его в топике?